# How to create an XML file with some elements containing CDATA

Tags: python, xml, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

Hi when I create an XML document it escape everything inside the CDATA.

so.py

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import codecs

#Open file
import codecs
f = codecs.open('so.xml','r','utf-8')
soup = BeautifulSoup(f.read(),"lxml-xml")
f.close()

def create_a_XML_file(content, filename = 'hello.xml'):
    f = codecs.open(filename, "w",'utf-8')
    f.write(str(content))
    f.close()

#Change or update some XML element value
soup.filename.notes.string = "économie"
soup.filename.description.string = "<![CDATA[<h1>économie</h1>]]"

#print(soup.prettify().encode('UTF-8'))

create_a_XML_file(soup, "so2.xml")
```

so.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<filename data="so.xml" mois="août">
   <notes name="économie">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</notes>
   <notes_script><![CDATA[L'Enquête sur le chômage
<ul>
  <li>économie</li>
  <li>données</li>
  <li>résultats</li>
  <li>après</li>
</ul>]]></notes_script>
<description></description>
</filename>
```

so2.xml (this is the result)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<filename data="so.xml" mois="août">
<notes name="économie">économie</notes>
<notes_script>L'Enquête sur le chômage
&lt;ul&gt;
  &lt;li&gt;économie&lt;/li&gt;
  &lt;li&gt;données&lt;/li&gt;
  &lt;li&gt;résultats&lt;/li&gt;
  &lt;li&gt;après&lt;/li&gt;
&lt;/ul&gt;</notes_script>
<description>&lt;![CDATA[&lt;h1&gt;économie&lt;/h1&gt;]]</description>
</filename>
```

I would like to know how to preserve the "<" and ">"

Comment: Generally you cannot control the output of CDATA. The serializer (the part that takes the in-memory DOM and writes the XML text stream) is not required to provide a means to control this.  There are some serializers that have options for this but it is non-standard.  You should accept that the format of the serialized version is immaterial as long as you can reconstruct the data correctly at the other end.

Comment: Look at it another way. When you request a web page the data may be encoded and decoded, compressed and decompressed while in transit. All you care about is that it arrives at your computer in a form the browser can render.  Think of XML the same way.  The fact that it can be more easily human-readable with CDATA sections is a side benefit, but the serializer is not required to do this.